# What is the error when cell text is deprecated?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

```
int p = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
[cell setText:[[array objectAtIndex: p] objectForKey: @"title"]];
```

I cannot find the reason for the error here . Im doing xml parsing and simply wanting to show the contents in a tableview but the program does not run as the deprecated error pops up which i cant figure out why.

Comment: btw, you can use `int p = indexPath.row;` too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the cell's `textLabel` instead:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[array objectAtIndex: p] objectForKey: @"title"];
```

The old `text` property on `UITableViewCell` was deprecated a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

`Cell.textLabel.text=[array objectAtIndex: p] objectForKey: @"title"]];`

It will not deprecate.

Comment: You forgot a 'square bracket' at `[array`